# how can Add a extra category attribute under general infomation tab

Tags: adminhtml, category, category-attribute

I want to create `yes/no`  `attributes` in magento category in gerenraltab. can you please tell me where to change in file any module create for it. or any tutrorial give me suggetion. adding attributes what to do for it?

Comment: but i create module for it. what type folder strucutre i want to follow? where to put this code for it. plese tell me?

Comment: Did you at least try to search online? The internet is full of explanations on how to do that. Take this for example: http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/